# Array diagonals python

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x

I have an array 10x10 and I need to address all the points that are on the diagonal between two points and check if there are in a list. I did this but I don't know why it isn't working:

To put you in context:

a = [i,j] b = [i,j], i and j = range(11)

The code below is supposed to work for a = [5,4]  b = [8,7] for example.

```
     ...
     elif (b[1] - a[1]) == (b[0] - a[0]):
        #to southeast, code for the other 3 cases are almost the same
        if b[0] > a[0] and b[1] > a[1]:
            n = a[0]
            m = a[1]
            while (n != b[0]) and (m != b[1]):
                n +=1
                m +=1 

                #don't think this part below is relevant
                if board[n][m] in somelist:
                    mov_inv += 1
                else:
                    mov_inv += 0
```

This is inside a function that returns False if mov_inv > 1 and True if mov_inv = 0 but it is not working that way. Hope you understand what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def diag(pointa, pointb):
    """ pointa and pointb are tuples
        returns a generator that yields values along the diagonal 
        from pointa to pointb"""

    if abs(pointa[0] - pointb[0]) != abs(pointa[1] - pointb[1]):
        #Sanity check. Diagonal are equal along x and y
        raise ValueError("Points {} and {} are not diagonal".format(pointa, pointb))
    x_dir = 1 if pointa[0] < pointb[0] else -1
    y_dir = 1 if pointa[1] < pointb[1] else -1
    while pointa != pointb:
        pointa = (pointa[0] + x_dir, pointa[1] + y_dir)
        yield pointa
```

The above doesn't yield `pointb` because you already know it

Answer (score 0):

```
board=xrange(10*10)
diagonal1=[board[C:(10-C)*10:10+1] for C in xrange(10)]
diagonal2=[board[C:(C*10)+1:10-1] for C in xrange(10)]
print 'diagonal ASC ',diagonal1
print 'diagonal DESC ',diagonal2
```

then you just check if a and b in same diagonal

```
assume a,b= [5,4] , [8,7]
def Square(m,n):
    return 10*(m-1)+n;
m,n=a
A=Square(m,n)
m,n=b
B=Square(m,n)
```

---

```
**print ('ASCENDENT',[diagonal1[x] for x in xrange(10) if A in diagonal[x] and B in diagonal[x]])**
```